# How to send ACK within the FUTURE?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am using an actor as a Sink as the following:

```
import akka.Done
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.{Message, TextMessage, WebSocketRequest}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, Materializer}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object WsActor {
  def props: Props = Props(new WsActor)
}

final class WsActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import com.sweetsoft.WsConnector._

  implicit val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = context.system.dispatcher
  implicit val actor = context.system

  // Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach,
  // emitted when the stream completes
  private val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
  Sink.foreach[Message] {
    case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
      println(message.text)
    case _ =>
      println("Unknown messages.")
  }

  //private val outgoing: Source[Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
  //  Source.maybe[Message]


  log.info("Websocket actor started.")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Initialized =>
      log.info("Initialization to receive messages via stream.")
      sender() ! Ack
    case Completed =>
      log.info("Streams completed.")
      sender() ! Ack
    case Msg(value) =>

      // the Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach
      // and it is completed when the stream completes
      val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[Done]] =
        Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(incoming, Source.single(TextMessage(value)))(Keep.left)

      // upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
      // completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
      // and closed is a Future[Done] representing the stream completion from above
      val (upgradeResponse, _) =
      Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest("ws://echo.websocket.org"), flow)

      upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
        if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
          Future.successful(Done)
        } else {
          throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
        }
      }.andThen {
        case Success(_) =>
          log.info("Sending ACK")
          sender() ! Ack
      }.onComplete {
        case Success(_) =>
          log.info("Success proceed")
        case Failure(ex) => log.error(ex.getMessage)
      }
    //sender() ! Ack
    case Failed(ex) =>
      log.info(s"Stream failed with ${ex.getMessage}.")
  }

}
```

The actor consumes the messages and redirect further to websocket server.

Somewhere in the code, I send an `Ack` to the `Sender` actor to signalize, that it ready to receive further messages. But the sender actor never receive the `Ack` message.

If I put `sender() ! Ack` the `FUTURE` chain, then it works as expected.

Is it possible to put `sender() ! Ack` within FUTURE` chain.

Answer (score 1):

Try remembering the sender on message receive and then using it later in the code instead of `sender()` instead of calling sender() downstream, this that value might not be constant during processing (e.g when receiving other messages in the meantime when ur current task does not block processing of the message queue due to futures )

```
case Msg(value) =>
  val sender = sender()
  .
  .
  sender ! Ack
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is the following lines:

```
}.andThen {
case Success(_) =>
  log.info("Sending ACK")
  sender() ! Ack
}.onComplete {
```

The `andThen` callback will be performed by another thread, and the `sender()` call may be empty (relatively lucky) or even another actor alltogether. You need to capture the sender before performing the first asynchronous action.

```
val respondTo = sender()
upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
  if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
    Future.successful(Done)
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
  }
}.andThen {
  case Success(_) =>
    log.info("Sending ACK")
    respondTo ! Ack
}.onComplete {
  case Success(_) =>
    log.info("Success proceed")
  case Failure(ex) => log.error(ex.getMessage)
}
```